# Hide navigation bar in master page depend on my user role

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i having a question when using web form, and i have a master page that contain my navigation, and i would like to ask is it possible after i login, my navigation bar can be customize base on different role (admin, student, staff)..

```
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" >
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu" style="text-align:center;">
                <li><a href="~/">Moderator</a></li>
                <li><a href="~/About.aspx">Supervisor</a></li>
                <li><a href="~/Contact.aspx">Student</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

so that is sample of contentplaceholder in my sitemaster, my idea is to hide moderator and supervisor when i log in with student, and i wish to use check the roles "student" then the sitemaster navigation bar of moderator and supervisor can hide from users, please do advice me there there are better solutions as this is only i know.. thanks..

Comment: you could setup an Enumeration and on the page load depending on what group or AccessLevel the user belongs to you can set the visibility I have done this with MenuItems many times before in the past..I would suggest doing this with MenuItems personally

Comment: thanks, i would try to research on enumeration..

Comment: I will post an example of what I am talking about and on The Page_Load event is where the code would go of the MasterPage.cs

Comment: What is your authentication method? Do you use a membership provider?

Comment: DJ KRAZE thanks for your sample, would try to understand about the concept,                                                        BuddhiP, may i know how to define the membership provider to my own user table? as i found it only link to the users table from the sample of asp.net default db.users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for your issue i have change your html code are as follows

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" >
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu" style="text-align:center;">
                <li id="li_moderator" runat="server"><a href="~/">Moderator</a></li>
                <li id="li_supervisor" runat="server"><a href="~/About.aspx">Supervisor</a></li>
                <li><a href="~/Contact.aspx">Student</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

than on ur server side coding after login verification and rights of the 
student you can hide or show your menu. use the following code

```
li_moderator.style.add("display","none")
  li_supervisor.style.add("display","none")
```

the same thing if you want to show in other case than use

```
  li_moderator.style.add("display","inherit")
  li_supervisor.style.add("display","inherit")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to suggest this:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent">
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu" style="text-align: center;">
                    <li id="menuModerator" runat="server"><a href="~/">Moderator</a></li>
                    <li id="menuSupervisor" runat="server"><a href="~/About.aspx">Supervisor</a></li>
                    <li id="menuStudent" runat="server"><a href="~/Contact.aspx">Student</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

In Site.Maste.cs inside Page_Load:

```
if (!Page.User.IsInRole("Moderator"))
   {
      menuModerator.Visible = false;
   }
```

For domain groups Page.User.IsInRole(@"Domain\GroupName")

Comment: wow thanks for your solutions! another question, sorry quite newbie.. when i click to another page(for eg: i click on menuStudent then it link to Contact.aspx, but the problem when i try to click any of the menu, it link me to wrong page, may i know any good solution to replace ~/Contact.aspx?

Comment: If my answer was helpful please mark it as correct. About your second question, sorry, can't get what is the problem. Can you rephrase?

Answer (score 1):

I setup my Enum like this..

```
public enum AccessRights
{
    LogisticsCoordinator_RW, //Read-Write,
    LogisticsCoordinator_R, //Read only Purchasing and Inventory
    ProcurementManager_RW, // Read-Write access to track purchase of Sand on monitor on hand Inventory
    ProcurementManager_R, //read access to Create Frac Jobs , Dispatch and reroute
    SystemAdministrator, //Full Rights to Vertex_Personnel only
    StudentManagement_R, //Read Access Only 
    AppAdministrator_R,
    NonAdmin,
    None,
    Full,
    Default
}
```

now I use LDAP/ActiveDirectory to determine the users access rights you can use SQL Server or some other means of checking user rights

This is just an Example of the code I am not going to paste the entire code but you should get the idea

```
 _ADPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADPath"];
 _Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ISDDomain"];
 _UserId = ((BasePage)Page).CurrentUser;
 string[] strUser = _UserId.Split('\\');
 if (strUser.Length == 2)
 {
     _UserId = strUser[1];
 }

 // uxLBLoginError.Text = "";
 try
 {
     LdapAuthentication la = new LdapAuthentication(_ADPath);

     if (!AdPassRequired)
     {
         //use this if password not required
         _authenticated = la.IsUserGroupMember(_UserId, AdGroupToPass);
     }
     //else
     //{
     //    // use this if password is required
     //    _authenticated = la.IsAuthenticated(_Domain, _UserId, strPassword);
     //}
     if (_authenticated)
     {
         //test the roles functionality
         ((BasePage)Page).GetDBRoleNames(_UserId);
         Session["User_Initial_Validated"] = true;
         Session["isDefault_Loaded"] = true;
         Session["AccessRights"] = AccessRights.Default;
         Session["UserId"] = _UserId;
         //Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
     }
```